# Heroku Build Failing (gyp rebuild command fails)

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have this problem when attempting to deploy to heroku:

```
...
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_BUILD_FLAGS=--no-warnings
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  16.13
       engines.npm (package.json):   8.1
       
       Resolving node version 16.13...
       Downloading and installing node 16.13.2...
       Bootstrapping npm 8.1 (replacing 8.1.2)...
       npm 8.1 installed
       
-----> Restoring cache
       Cached directories were not restored due to a change in version of node, npm, yarn or stack
       Module installation may take longer for this build
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       npm ERR! code 1
       npm ERR! path /tmp/build_f02b6ec2/node_modules/java
       npm ERR! command failed
       npm ERR! command sh -c node-gyp rebuild
       npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
       npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.0
       npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.2 | linux | x64
       npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.8.10 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
       npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.13.2/node-v16.13.2-headers.tar.gz
       npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.13.2/node-v16.13.2-headers.tar.gz
       npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.13.2/SHASUMS256.txt
       npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.13.2/SHASUMS256.txt
       npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python3
       npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
       npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   
...
```

I attempted to solve the problem a variety of ways, like add `--no-warnings` to the Node Build Flags (You can try that [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#build-flags))
I also tried all of the recommendations in the Heroku page to debug builds. None helped.

Comment: [Please don't add "solved" to your title or question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/248627). Just accept the answer that answers your question. (And [don't assume that this is solved _optimally_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer): "You can also accept your own answer, but you must wait 48 hours to do so. After all, someone else may come along with an even better solution to your problem!"

Comment: @Chris true. Thanks for the advice. Edits made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your (my) problem is in the package.json. You have `jdbc` installed, (I know this because the error appears here: `npm ERR! path /tmp/build_f02b6ec2/node_modules/java`) which seems to be causing the problem. Try to remove it and this will solve your problem.